# Unable to run Visual Studio Android Emulator on windows 10 pro

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, windows-10

Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 on Windows 10.

Below is the one of the log...
12/30/2015 8:56:55 AM : [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 17 Platforms: 2
12/30/2015 8:57:31 AM : [Informational] Waiting to launch device...
12/30/2015 8:57:31 AM : [Informational] Launching Device: 5.5" Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI Phone
12/30/2015 8:57:31 AM : [Informational] Validating emulator arguments...
12/30/2015 8:57:31 AM : [Informational] Determining if emulator is already running...
12/30/2015 8:58:31 AM : [Critical] An error occurred that prevented the operation from completing successfully.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you could try:

1. Uninstall the emulator/android sdk and reinstall.
2. Check that your account is in the Hyper-V Administrators group.
   Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > User Accounts > Manage User Accounts > Advanced > Advanced User Management. Under Groups.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same, least-helpful message. By chance, do you get different results using either of the following methods?

- Run the **Visual Studio Emulator for Android** as an administrator.
- Double-click the name of the image (instead of clicking the 'play' button').

It's working for me now and, while I know that second one sounds ridiculous, I did get a different result by double-clicking the name of the image I wanted to run.